# stop text-area from resizing in Safari

Tags: css, safari, textarea

Safari gives resize handles for text-areas. anyone knows how to stop that? thanx

Comment: why? it was added as a usability feature.

Comment: PS Chrome also has them, and other browsers are contemplating adding the feature (I know Asa Dotzler was pushing for Mozilla to add this to Firefox)

Comment: i don't mind the the vertical stretch. it's the horizontal resize that messes up the layout.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable resizable property of TextArea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235142/how-to-disable-resizable-property-of-textarea)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use CSS3 to prevent the resizing:

```
textarea {
   resize: none;
}
```

Comment: I believe so. Safari and Chrome also respect the min/max height and width property so you can control how much resizing your users can do.

Comment: If you want to allow your users to resize the text box vertically, but prevent horizontal resizing, you can set the resize property to vertical. (http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#resize0)